# 夕日にすることなく光の当たり方を変えたい

Tags: unity3d

Directional LightのRotationのXを移動させることで、光の当たり方や、影が落ちる位置を変えようとしました。
すると、空が赤くなり夕焼けのようになりました。（もっと移動させると暗くなり夜になった雰囲気でした）

これは仕様なのでしょうか？
色が変わることなく、光のあたり方や影の落ちる位置だけを変えることはできないのでしょうか？
もしできない場合は、別途ライトを用意するのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: マニュアルはこちらが関連しそうです。 - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lighting.html